# How to make the slider width change when Resize. JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When I change the width of the page it does not stretch in width. Sorry for my English. #How to make the slider width change when Resize.# For some reason, it remembers the first width.
Resize *width* and *transform* Please help me. I want to change the width of the screen and have the slider adjust to the width. This code is in pure Javascript. Who can help. I've been racking my head for 3 days, I'm just a beginner.

```js
(function() {
                    let curTranslateX = 0;
                    let curPageNum = 0;
                    let dots = null;
                    let slideWidth = 0;
                    let duration = 300;
                    let pointStart, pointMove, pointEnd;
                    let slidePositions = [];
                    let isAutoLoop = false;
                    let hasArrow = true;
                    let scrollbar = {
                        el: '.slide-navbar',
                        isHide: true,
                        canClick: true
                    };
                    let slideContainer = document.querySelector('.container_slider');
                    let slideWrapper = slideContainer.querySelector('.slide_wrapper');
                    let slideItems = [...slideWrapper.querySelectorAll('.slide-item')];
                    const utils = {
                        hasClass: function(elem, className) {
                            return(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)')).test(elem.className);
                        },
                        addClass: function(elem, className) {
                            if(!arguments.length) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if(typeof className === 'undefined' || this.hasClass(elem, className)) {
                                return;
                            }
                            let newClasses = elem.className.split(' ');
                            newClasses.push(className);
                            elem.className = newClasses.join(' ');
                        },
                        removeClass: function(elem, className) {
                            if(!arguments.length) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if(typeof className === 'undefined' || !this.hasClass(elem, className)) {
                                return;
                            }
                            let classes = elem.className.split(' ');
                            classes = classes.filter(cls => cls !== className);
                            elem.className = classes.join(' ');
                        },
                        isMobile: function() {
                            return(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i).test(navigator.userAgent);
                        }
                    }
                    var slide = {
                        init: (function() {
                            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                                dots = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slide-navbar span')];
                                dots.forEach(dot => {
                                    utils.addClass(dot, 'dot');
                                });
                                if(utils.isMobile()) {
                                    pointStart = 'touchstart';
                                    pointMove = 'touchmove';
                                    pointEnd = 'touchend';
                                } else {
                                    pointStart = 'pointerdown';
                                    pointMove = 'pointermove';
                                    pointEnd = 'pointerup';
                                }
                                slide.bindTouchEvent();
                                slide.setCurrentPage();
                            }.bind(slide), false);
                        })(),
                        setTranslate: function(duration, offsetX, ...yz) {
                            this.style = `transition-duration: ${duration}ms; transform: translate3d(${offsetX}px, 0px, 0px);`;
                            curTranslateX = offsetX;
                        },
                        setCurrentPage: function(num) {
                            if(curPageNum !== -1) {
                                utils.removeClass(dots[curPageNum], 'dot-active');
                                utils.removeClass(slideItems[curPageNum], 'slide-active');
                            }
                            num = (typeof num === 'undefined') ? 0 : num;
                            curPageNum = num;
                            utils.addClass(dots[curPageNum], 'dot-active');
                            utils.addClass(slideItems[curPageNum], 'slide-active');
                        },
                        gotoPage: function(num) {
                            if(num < 0 || num > dots.length - 1) {
                                return;
                            }
                            slide.setTranslate.call(slideWrapper, duration, slidePositions[num]);
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                slide.setCurrentPage(num);
                            }, duration / 2);
                        },
                        bindTouchEvent: function() {
                            slideWidth = slideItems[0].scrollWidth;
                            slideContainer.style.width = `${slideWidth}px`;
                            let negMaxWidth = -slideWidth * (slideItems.length - 1);
                            for(let i = 0, wtd = 0; i < slideItems.length; i++, wtd -= slideWidth) {
                                slidePositions.push(wtd);
                            }
                            let startX,
                                startY,
                                initialPos = 0,
                                moveDist = 0,
                                direction = 0,
                                isMove = false,
                                startT = 0,
                                isPointOut = true;
                            slideContainer.addEventListener(pointStart, function(e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                if(!isPointOut && e.touches.length !== 1) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                let startPoint = e.touches[0];
                                startX = startPoint.pageX;
                                startY = startPoint.pageY;
                                initialPos = curTranslateX;
                                startT = +new Date();
                                isMove = false;
                                isPointOut = false;
                            }.bind(this), false);
                            slideContainer.addEventListener(pointMove, function(e) {
                                if(isPointOut) {
                                    return
                                }
                                let movePoint = e.touches[0];
                                let deltaX = movePoint.pageX - startX;
                                let deltaY = movePoint.pageY - startY;
                                let offsetX = initialPos + deltaX;
                                if(offsetX > 0 || offsetX < negMaxWidth) {
                                    offsetX -= (deltaX / 2);
                                }
                                this.setTranslate.call(slideWrapper, 0, offsetX);
                                isMove = true;
                                deltaX = offsetX - initialPos;
                                moveDist = deltaX;
                                direction = deltaX > 0 ? 0 : 1;
                            }.bind(this), false);
                            slideContainer.addEventListener(pointEnd, function(e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                let deltaT = +new Date() - startT;
                                if(!isMove) {
                                    if(utils.hasClass(e.target, 'slide-button-prev')) {
                                        if(curPageNum === 0) {
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        slide.gotoPage.call(e.target, curPageNum - 1);
                                    } else if(utils.hasClass(e.target, 'slide-button-next')) {
                                        if(curPageNum === dots.length - 1) {
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        slide.gotoPage.call(e.target, curPageNum + 1);
                                    }
                                    return;
                                }
                                if(isPointOut) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                isPointOut = true;
                                if(deltaT < 300 || Math.abs(moveDist) > slideWidth / 2) {
                                    offsetX = direction === 0 ? curTranslateX + slideWidth - moveDist : curTranslateX - slideWidth - moveDist;
                                    offsetX = offsetX > 0 ? 0 : offsetX;
                                    offsetX = offsetX < negMaxWidth ? negMaxWidth : offsetX;
                                } else {
                                    offsetX = curTranslateX - moveDist;
                                }
                                slide.setTranslate.call(slideWrapper, duration, offsetX);
                                let newPageNum = Math.round(Math.abs(offsetX) / slideWidth);
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    this.setCurrentPage(newPageNum);
                                }, duration / 2);
                            }.bind(this), false);
                        },
                    };
                    
                    
                })();
```

```css
.container_box {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}



.container_slider {
  position: relative;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}



.slide_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.container_slider .slide-item {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  user-select: none;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide-navbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 4px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.dot-active {
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: rgba(233, 233, 233, .9);
}

.slide-button-prev,
.slide-button-next {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: rgba(233, 233, 233, .9);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.slide-button-prev {
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);  
}
.slide-button-next {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container_box">

<div class="container_slider">
  <div class="slide_wrapper">
    <div class="slide-item slide-active" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    <div class="slide-item" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div class="slide-item" style="background-color:black;"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="control_slider slide-button-prev"><</div>
  <div class="control_slider slide-button-next">></div>




<div class="slide-navbar">
    <span class="dot dot-active">1</span>
    <span class="dot">2</span>
    <span class="dot">3</span>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged java?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I change the width of the page it does not stretch in width. Sorry for my English.

Comment: **JavaScript is *not* Java**, despite their similar names. I removed the [tag:java] tag.

Comment: I corrected a syntax error in your html. See changes by click on "edited x mins ago".

Answer (score 0):

First: I replaced the `<` and `>` by `&gt;` and `&lt;`:

```
<div class="control_slider slide-button-prev">&lt;</div>
<div class="control_slider slide-button-next">&gt;</div>
```

To your question:

I found out that in `bindTouchEvent: function() {}`

exists the line

> slideContainer.style.width = `${slideWidth}px`;

This line is in charge to set a fix width. If you comment out this line all single slide-items reacts on resize.

Comment: Thank you, how to make sure that the width is not remembered in the div when the page is first opened. If you change the width of the page, it still uses the width that was at the first. (-1234px)

<div class="slide_wrapper" style="transition-duration: 300ms; transform: translate3d(-1234px, 0px, 0px);">

Comment: I dot not understand your comment. I opend your provided code in windows with different size and also changed the size of opening window, the sliders change thier size

Comment: Have you tried out my change?

Comment: Yes made your changes. But if we change the width of the page, then the slides indent. Picture https://ibb.co/rb1ZmJ9